# Django: How to next process Stripe's ACH Verification Error

Tags: django, error-handling, stripe-payments

I want to be able to act on an error that happens when I run one of the commands to interface stripe. I can see the error, but can't seem to capture it.

When I run a the verification for stripe's ACH payment format and use bad deposist, I get the following error:

```
in handle_error_response
raise err
stripe.error.CardError: Request req_UyfXgBVRSOqUuJ: The amounts provided do not match the amounts that were sent to the bank account.
```

How do I take this and do something meaningful with it. My code looks like this:

```
ank_account_response = customer.sources.retrieve(request.stripe_id)
bank_account_response.verify(amounts=[request._post['deposit_1'], request._post['deposit_2']])
```

The error appears on the last line of code. I want either set do something like `output = bank_account_response.verify...` or `try: bank_account_response`, but I can't get it to work.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should handle error response something like below.

```
try:
    bank_account_response.verify(amounts=[request._post['deposit_1'], request._post['deposit_2']])

except CARD_ERROR as card_error:

    return JsonResponse(status_code=400,
                        message=card_error.message)
```